# How can I record a macro on the fly with Black Widow Ultimate?

Tags: keyboard, macros, razer-keyboard

I believe that Black Widow Ultimate can record macros on the fly. However, they are recorded with a delay in the time you take to press the keystrokes by default. Is it, in fact, possible to do this without delay/on the fly?

Answer (score 5):

I have the Black widow Ultimate and here's how you do recording on the fly

Function F9

type your key combination that you wish you record

Function F9 again to stop (a flashing indicator will show you it has stopped)

Then hit the key combo that you want it to be recorded on like M1

To get rid of the timing you have to manually delete the timings in the macro after it is recorded.  A new macro will show up in your macro list that was not there before.  That will be your newly recorded macro.  There is no way of setting the automatic key recording to have no time recorded with it.  You simply have to remove it manually.

You can however export the macro which will export in xml, insert it into a text editor like TextPad and change the entire macro's delays all at once doing a search and replace using RegEx in the Find/Replace dialog.  Turn on the RegEx find feature and use

```
<Delay>[\d]*</Delay>
```

as your search feature.  This will find all of the Delay references with numbers in them.  In the replace part of the dialog put

```
<Delay>0</Delay>
```

Now you can reimport the XML code with no delays. A little tedious however worth it for long macros.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can delete the delay by going into the driver, going to the *Manage Macros* tab, your on the fly macro should show in the "Macro Name" drop down as "New Macro1" or so, and you can highlight the delays and click the *Delete* option above it.

Answer (score 2):

As of software version 1.18 there is an option to do this.

In Razr synapse go to the Macros section where you can edit the macro you recorded. They now have options for Recording Delay, Default the delay to a second value, or No Delay.

Answer (score 1):

From looking over the documentation provided by Razer I do not see a way to default the "on the fly" macro recording to remove the delay in between key presses.

You can, however, set the delay in key presses if you prerecord your macros. See pages [5-6 in the user manual](http://www.razersupport.com/master-guides/Razer%20BlackWidow%20Ultimate%20MasterGuide.pdf) for how to edit the delay in your macro buy using the Razer BlackWidow Ultimate Configurator that is included with the [driver package](http://www.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=556).